# Doctrine2 Mapping Problems on a Symfony2 Project

Tags: database, database-design, annotations, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities Item and Itemimage. The relationship between Item to Itemimage is OneToMany Unidirectional with JoinColumn. I took help from doctrine documentation. The OneToMany unidirectional with JoinColumn is achieved with the ManyToMany Annotation:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Itemimage")
 * @JoinTable(name="itemimage",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="itemid")}
 *      )
 */
```

Where:

- image_id: itemid is a property in the Itemimage Entity
- item_id: is the primary key property of the Item Entity

I made a property $images in Item Entity and gave it the above docblock. The problem is that when I tried updating the schema. I get a doctrine error: "**The Table 'itemimage' already exists**". I'm sure that is not the case. I have no idea what to do.

Please help me with this.

Thanks! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to be:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Itemimage")
 * @JoinTable(name="itemimage_map",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

leading to the creation of a third table (itemimage_map) that will contain just the mapping of the other two tables. It is not an existing table you have to join there. That table will contain item_id and image_id which are the primary keys of tables you want to map.